# FTP: executable file changing to a text file during download

Tags: macos, unix, ftp

I have unix executable files along with a mac OS X app that I have transferred to my FTP server. When I download these files after uploading them, the unix executables download as TextEdit documents. Like wise with the Application, when downloaded it says "The application MyApp cannot be opened". I believe this is because when it downloads the app it downloads the unix executable in the directory MyApp/Contents/MacOS/Myapp as a text document. So I assume the issue is the same with both problems I am having. How can this be fixed. Also I would also like to have the same custom icon that I uploaded the file with. Note: The check sum for the original file and the downloaded file from the ftp server are the same.

Answer (score -1):

## TLDR:

This is normal when you download in ASCII mode. Switch to binary download

## Background:

Back in ye days of lore when we only had english on computers and no accent, trema's or other interesting characters and when memor was still very scarce we use ASCII to represent letters and number. ASCSII contains 127 entries.

127 entries fitr in 7 bits, while a current regular byte is 8 bits.<sup>*1</sup>

If you send over all 8 bits then you are wasting (then very expensive and limited) bandwidth<sup>*2</sup>, so the 8 bit got dropped. This worked fine for text files.  If you tranfered binary (non_ASCII) data then you needed to explicitly tell FTP to download all 8 bits by switching to binary mode.

---

<sup>*1: As well as doing helpful things like converting your text between remote format to local. E.g. from mainframe EBDIC to ASCII, changing line ending between etc.</sup>

*2: Bandwidth example:

ASCII mode:

```
AAAAAAAB BBBBBBCC CCCCCDDD DDDDEEEE EEEFFFFF FFFGGGGG GGHHHHHH H...   
                                                        ^^^^^^
                                                        Savings
```

Binary mode:

```
AAAAAAA- BBBBBBB- CCCCCCC- DDDDDDD- EEEEEEE- FFFFFFF- GGGGGGG- H....
```

Comment: Thanks  @Hennes for your comment but I am still having this problem. Once I connect to my ftp server it says 'Using binary mode to transfer files.' . Even so I type binary and it says '200 TYPE is now 8-bit binary' and I upload the file and try to download it and I still have the same problem

Comment: Now that is weird. Csan you checksum it (e.g. MD5 it) and see it it fail on both binary upload and binary download? ).

Comment: The check sum for the original file and the downloaded file from the ftp server are the same

Comment: Hmm, than I was wrong. It is not getting corrupted due to wrong FTP settings. I'll delete the wrong answer in a bit. Meanwhile Please use the [edit](http://superuser.com/posts/1035003/edit) link to add this information to the original post. Also make test (and add to the OP that you tested) an upload to make sure that the files on the server are fine (so we know we do not have this  BINARY (fine) -> Upload (Binary, corrupted).    followed by (Binary, corrupted, MD5 taken). -> Download (still same corruption).

Comment: I've edited the question but I don't understand the second part of your comment.

Comment: I was referring to `the check sum for the original file and the downloaded file from the ftp server are the same`. Is that the original file on the server (which could already be corrected in an earlier stage) or one on your local computer which you checksummed, uploaded, downloaded and compared the checksum with.

Comment: Your solution may well be correct, but your cutesy story is BS. Text mode has always transferred in 8 bit mode, it just changes line endings between UNIX (and modern Mac) style LFs, DOS style CRLFs, and VAX/VMS (and classic Mac) CRs.

Comment: Yes the what you said. The check sum from my local computer is the same as the check some of the file that has been downloaded from the ftp server @Hennes